# SQL Server datepart - only match by year

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

In my db, I have a date in the format yyyy-mm-dd, and in my php file, a year stored as a string (ex 2013). I would like to select rows from my table where the date in the db is matched with the stored date.

I have tried using DATEPART(), but it is returning bool false.

How can I query the db and match the php string with the date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQL Server you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE year(date) = $yearfromphp
```

If your date is not stored as a datetime field, but as `yyyy-mm-dd` you could use

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE left(date,4) = $yearfromphp
```

Comment: So if the column name was create_date, I would use WHERE year(create_date) = $yearfromphp?

Comment: @Jordy assuming `$yearfromphp` references the PHP value correctly, yes. I'm not familiar with PHP.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date_column` LIKE '$year%';
```

Comment: why would you want to use a LIKE as oppose to a SQL function?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, I wanted it as a column name.

Comment: same question. why would you use LIKE rather than a built in SQL function that finds the actual year?

Comment: Because the variable contains string, which somehow could not match exactly. It's not way so strict, However, maybe the idea is to be strict or I'm wrong. Point it if it's better to extract with an SQL function.